# Akka actor does not receive message with DistributedPubSub

Tags: scala, akka

I try to make akka cluster with distributed messages work, but I'm stuck. My actor is properly started and subscribed to topic but no messages are received. Here is the code

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.cluster.client.ClusterClient.Publish
import akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSub
import akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSubMediator.{Subscribe, SubscribeAck}

case object DistributedMessage

object ClusterExample extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem")
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ClusterExample]), "clusterExample")
}

class ClusterExample extends Actor {
  private val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator

  mediator ! Subscribe("content", self)

  override def receive = {
    case SubscribeAck(Subscribe("content", None, `self`)) =>
      (1 to 100) foreach (_ => {
        mediator ! Publish("content", msg = DistributedMessage)
      })

    case DistributedMessage => println("received message from queue!")
  }
}
```

And here is configuration:

```
akka {
  log-dead-letters = 0
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = on

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    enable-additional-serialization-bindings = on
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552

      bind-hostname = "0.0.0.0"
      bind-port = 2552
    }
  }
  extensions = ["akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSub"]

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"
    ]
  }
}
```

"received message from queue" is actually never printed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silly mistake. So, the problem was invalid import. This:

```
import akka.cluster.client.ClusterClient.Publish
```

should be replaced by:

```
import akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish
```